# Git context menu in Windows Exporer has a "git bash" option but it doesn't work

Tags: windows, git, bash, command-line, windows-7

The default git distribution for windows contains, besides the CLI tools, a shell integration, i.e. a context menu for Windows Explorer. This context menu has a "Git bash" option which I suppose should open a Git bash prompt `cd`'d to the current directory. But instead, the git bash window **opens and immediately closes**, giving me no chance to even see what it says inside it. **Any fix?**

Note: Opening Git Bash from the Windows Start Menu works fine, but if I open it that way, then I need to manually `cd` to the needed dir.

Comment: "Not related to programming"? The help center explicitly says that questions about programming tools are ok on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what distribution/version of git I had before, but now I installed "Git for Windows, version 2.10.1, 32-bit" from https://git-scm.com/download/win and the problem is gone.